# Task ID in Subject of email alerts

Tags: alert, list

I want to get task ID in subject line of email alerts from a particular list.

How to do it? Which files I need to modify to get the desired result?

and

Will the change in default template will be for all list or it can be made for only particular list?

I use WSS 3.0

Thanks!

-saumil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a full tutorial on customizing the task alert email here: [Customizing Alert Notifications and Alert Templates in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdeveloperdocs/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0)

> 1. ```
>     Create a working copy of AlertTemplates.xml.
>    ```
> 2. ```
>     Edit the working copy that you just created.
>    ```
> 3. ```
>     Use the stsadm command to read the changed templates into the
>    ```
>
> database. `STSADM -o updatealerttemplates -url <http://urlname> -filename <your working copy filename>`
> 4.      Restart IIS.

And when you get some problems there is another tutorial here: [Customizing Task alert email problem](https://web.archive.org/web/20100923193850/http://spideas.wordpress.com:80/2009/01/16/customizing-task-alert-email/)

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply...
I need to know what file to change to get Task ID Number in Subject of email.

Comment: You said that in your question already. You need to work on `AlertTemplates.xml` and you might have a variable for TaskID, but you most probably have to code that yourself.